# PHP escaping concatenated string

Tags: php

I have a seemingly easy task, but I'm struggling a bit. I know that I need to escape the quotes, but I cant seem to get the combination correct.

```
$referringURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "<a href = ".$referringURL./MyAccount/SearchUser.aspx" class = "back">Return to Search Users page</a>";
```

Comment: just escape any `"` in the html wherey ou DON'T want to leave "string mode" in php, `echo "<a href=\"foo\">hi mom</a>";`

Answer (score 1):

It is worth from time to time mix quotes

```
echo '<a href = "' . $referringURL . '/MyAccount/SearchUser.aspx" class = "back">Return to Search Users page</a>';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Forget escaping, use **[Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)**

```
echo <<<HTML
<a href = "$referringURL/MyAccount/SearchUser.aspx" class = "back">
Return to Search Users page
</a>
HTML;
```

The actual problem in your code is a missing `"` before **./MyAccount** and 3 unescaped `"` after that

Answer (score 0):

Have fun

```
$referringURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "<a href = '".$referringURL."/MyAccount/SearchUser.aspx' class='back'>Return to Search Users page</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid quotation problems it is possible to separate the main string and the strings to be inserted by using `sprintf` : each string to insert is represented in the main string by `%s`, then you add as many strings as `%s` you have:

```
<?php
$referringURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$s = sprintf( "<a href = '%s' class = '%s'>Return to Search Users page</a>",
              $referringURL . "/MyAccount/SearchUser.aspx",
              "back" );
echo $s;
?>
```

This method is less confusing when concatenating multiple strings.